How to disable wrap text in oracle fusion BI template web layout? (Interactive layout )
I am not finding wraptext option in oracle fusion web-based layout (interactive report) in BI publisher
i tried with column width and height seems like it is not the solution , when i run the report in excel content is in wrap text
